# Removing dead code leads to error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler, spring-tool-suite, dead-code

I'm using Eclipse 4.3 Kepler (actually STS 3.6.1).

I ran into some code:

```
private String someMethod(String myParam) {
    try {
        MyInterface myVar = (MyInterface) domeSomething(myParam);
        if (myVar != null) {
            return myVar.methodThatReturnsString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
    return ""; // eclipse marks this as dead code
}
```

(As you'd expect, the `doSomething()` method throws some exception, and it returns an interface more general than `MyInterface`.)

Eclipse underlines the last return statement as *dead code*, and if I remove it as the quickfix suggests, I and up with the "This method should return a result of type String" error.

Why is the last return statement dead code? Is it because of the class cast? Say that `doSomething()` could return null, if you cast it, would that throw a class cast exception?

And, why does Eclipse suggest that I fix the error with something that leads to a *dead code* warning? Is it because Eclipse can't predict this?

Comment: Remove the `return ""` from within the `catch` block. Mind you, `someMethod` excepts `String`, but you're trying to return `MyInterface`...seems like you have bigger issues

Comment: Really sorry about that mistake, it does return a String. Corrected now :)

Comment: Something completely different: I like your logo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no dead code in your posted code. The only problem I can see is here:

```
if (myVar != null) {
    return myVar;
}
```

You're returning a `MyInterface` when you should return a `String`. The compiler will complain about it and it's right.

Also, as a better alternative, you should not directly return inside the `try` or `catch` block, instead design a single place after this block to return the result. This will make your code avoid any *dead code* compiler error. Your could should look like:

```
private String someMethod(String myParam) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        MyInterface myVar = (MyInterface) domeSomething(myParam);
        if (myVar != null) {
            result = myVar.methodThatReturnsString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle the exception
        //basic handling shown
        System.out.println("Warning. There was a problem executing someMethod:");
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Really sorry, there was a mistake in my post. It should return a String. Corrected now. Once again, sorry :)

Comment: @eivamu anyway. That was the only *problem* in your code. Apart of that, follow the last part of my post.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions. Anyone know why Eclipse can't "see beyond" this?

Comment: @eivamu I can only guess that you didn't validate if `myvar` was `null` and you were just directly returning `myVar.methodThatReturnsString();` , which is a direct `return` from the `try`, then you had another direct `return` in `catch`, so the compiler will know that both branches `try` and `catch` return something, so **everything else after the `try-catch` block of code will be threat as dead code**. Since your current piece of code doesn't show that, there was no need to fix this anymore.

Comment: +1 for `you should not directly return inside the try or catch block`. I'd add `finally` to that statement as well. I'm not a zealot for "only one return", but adhering to it in this scenario is well-advised.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely using Eclipse's annotation `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull` on the method `domeSomething`.

In that case, the Eclipse compiler knows, that the variable does not refer to `null` and thus the code will either return the variable (BTW: This is another compiler error, as the variable is not of type `String`) or throw an exception which will return the empty string. The last line is then indeed dead code. Hence, the warning.

However, removing that last line leads to code that does not comply with the JLS. Hence, the compiler error.

Comment: That's not the case (the Eclipse annotation is not used), however it might be the case in similar situations, so thanks for the useful suggestion.